# What sort of action is it for a Pact of the Chain warlock's familiar to attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, warlock, actions, familiars

I've seen the clarification in the [PHB Errata](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf) which states:

> ***Pact of the Chain (p. 107).*** When you let your familiar attack, it does so with its reaction.

However, I wondered if there had been some sort of further official clarification on this since the errata came out... It also raises the question as to whether the familiar would still have both its movement and action left for the turn in which it attacks.

Comment: I don't really understand the need for clarification in the errata, if my answer isn't sufficient you will have to specify what you feel is unclear.

Answer (score 19):

### It's a reaction, as stated in the errata

The errata clearly states that when the Warlock lets their familiar attack, the familiar uses their reaction to do so.

> it also raises the question as to whether the familiar would still have both its movement and action left for the turn in which it attacks.

No, because the familiar didn't necessarily have actions or movement on that turn in the first place - the Pact of the Chain familiar can only attack when the warlock takes the Attack action, which usually happens only on the warlock's turn. It can also happen on other turns, even the familiar's own, if the warlock Readied an Attack action, but no matter the turn the Attack happens on, it's always a reaction for the familiar to make the Pact of the Chain attack. If it happens on the familiar's own turn, it doesn't lose any movement or actions for it.

The familiar will have actions and movement as usual on their own turn, but cannot use their action to attack on their own because of the limitations of *Find familiar* ([spell description on D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar)).

> Your familiar acts independently of you, but it always obeys your commands.  In combat, it rolls its own initiative and acts on its own turn. A familiar can't attack, but it can take other actions as normal.

*Pact of the Chain* exception to the above

> Additionally, when you take the Attack action, you can forgo one of your own attacks to allow your familiar to make one attack of its own with its reaction.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71291/discussion-on-answer-by-kviiri-what-sort-of-action-is-it-for-a-warlocks-pact-of).

Answer (score 1):

It uses the reaction as stated, not the action or movement.

However (contrary to other answers) *Sage Advice* has suggested that when the warlock gives up its action, the familiar then uses its reaction to attack *on its own turn*—it doesn’t do so immediately on the warlock’s turn.

[Jeremy Crawford responds to a question about the attack's timing here](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2014/09/06/warlock-pact-of-the-chain/):

> *If a Warlock forgoes an attack to let his Pact of the Chain familiar attack does it occur immediately or on it's next turn?*
>
> **I would rule that the warlock commands the familiar to attack, and then the familiar does so on its turn.**

Comment: To be fair, the way Crawford words that indicates that it's not actually stated that way anywhere in the books; the Pact of the Chain feature never mentions when the familiar's attack occurs other than you giving the command "when you take the Attack action". Seems to be a slight gap in the rules.

Comment: Yep, hence why I went with “suggested” rather than “ruled”, though it's the closest we have to a decision from someone official.  As you note, the original and errata wording on this one are both pretty vague.

Comment: FYI, Crawford's tweets are not "Sage Advice"; that's just the name of a third-party site that compiles designer tweets. The real/official Sage Advice is [the rules answers/advice column on the official D&D website](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/sage-advice), as well as the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/sage-advice/sage-advice-compendium) ([DDB link here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/sac/sage-advice-compendium)) that compiles these official rulings into a single document.